# How to set product page to 2 columns-left instead of 1 column

Tags: layout, magento-1, products-view

How to set the product page layout to 2 columns-left instead of 1 column.

I've had a look around in `catalog.xml` but no joy, I've been looking for `catalog_product_view`

Answer (score 6):

Make your changes in the `local.xml` of your template folder to make sure they're not overwritten. If it doesn't exist you can go ahead and create it.

Then add:

```
[...]
<catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="root">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
[...]
```

And that should do the trick.

---

<sup>For details, refer to **"How to use local.xml / theme.xml"** in [What is the correct way/approach to modify a Magento template?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72760/what-is-the-correct-way-approach-to-modify-a-magento-template/72903#72903)</sup>

Comment: Nicely done - but this is all product pages. If it's one-at-a-time use my solution.

Comment: So now we wait and see if he want's to do a one time fix or all pages ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can do it via the backend but you can only do that per product ? i have over 3000. I will try the Local.xml file now but thatsnot working, I didnt have a Local.xml so i created one but no success

Comment: Where did you create the local.xml?

Answer (score 2):

Easy-peasy - there's a backend setting for that in the product edit screen > Design:

[image]

You can also use the "update attributes" mass action in the product grid to update many products at once:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

change layout of  product view page to 2 columns-left instead of 1 column

Go to file path by FTP :- app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml

Catalog Product View (Any)
    
    
        page/1column.phtml
        
    
 can change 1column to 2columns-left.phtml.

We can also use local.xml need to be add

page/2columns-left.phtml

Comment: Could you please tell me where this can be done in Magento 2.. i mean the file path or location..There is no such default/layout/catalog.xml in Magento 2 if im right