# What is the correct way/approach to modify a Magento template?

Tags: layout, magento-1, theme, rwd-theme, local.xml

Please suggest me the right approach, I want to customize the "EMAIL to Friend" page into pop up window, when user click on the button (email this product). By enabling template hinting, I found out that the button is rendered with

> frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/sharing.phtml

And the corresponding layout file is `catalog.xml` (in frontend/rwd/default/layout)

So I created a `local.xml` in the same folder where `catalog.xml` exist with the following code (just that I have given `test.phtml` instead of `sharing.phtml`, just to 'Debug')

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>

        <catalog-product-view>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.sharing" as="sharing" template="catalog/product/view/test.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </catalog-product-view>

    </default>
</layout>
```

But nothing happens, I mean how I can change (overwrite) the default design of theme, without modifying existing `xml` and `phtml` files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you should put inside your `local.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.sharing">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>catalog/product/view/test.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

### Mistakes that you have done

- You used **two layout update handles**: `default` and `catalog-product-view`. That is wrong. You only need one layout update handle. The right one that you should use here is `catalog_product_view`
- So `catalog-product-view` is unknown for magento. The proper name is `catalog_product_view`
- Since sharing block is already defined via `catalog.xml`, now you need to refer that block and then change the template by adding action `setTemplate`. That is what the above script does.

Hope you get the idea

Comment: I used your local.xml , still its showing up the existing one ( i have created an test.phtml ) in the specified folder

Comment: did you clear your cache ? this is supposed to work, if you have done everything correctly.

Comment: yup caching is disabled in my case and I have reindexed also( I guess its wasn't needed)

Comment: add this `<reference name="content"><block type="core/template" name="test.block" template="catalog/product/view/test.phtml" /></reference>` directly under the node `<catalog_product_view>`. and look whether test.phtml file content is available at the bottom part of a product view page

Comment: No luck bro still

Comment: mate it came up suddenly , as soon as I DELETED my old commented my old code .. THanks ..good eve

Comment: if that is not worked, that means you have done some mistake in the declaration of the files involved. you should dig more and find the mistake that you have done

Comment: Great, if my answer helped, feel free to accept it as the right answer. Thanks

Comment: already did ...

Answer (score 10):

I'll try to give a general answer.

### How to change templates

In your theme, you can override any `phtml` files from the default theme or parent theme. Copy the original file to `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/[path/to/phtml]` and make your changes.

If you don't have a project specific custom theme yet, for example because you just bought a theme, make sure to create one at

```
app/design/frontend/[original-package]/[project-name]
```

It will inherit from `[original-package]/[default]`, you do not need to copy everything from default, just the files where you need to make changes.

**Module specific changes**

An alternative to overriding the `phtml` file, is to change the template path. This can usually be done in layout XML like this:

```
<reference name="the-block-name">
    <action method="setTemplate"><name>path/to/new/template.phtml</name></action>
</reference>
```

But this is intended to be used by modules who need to switch a template, not for theme specific changes. The new template should be in `base/default` then.

### How to use local.xml / theme.xml

The `local.xml` file must be in the directory of the actual theme you are using, i.e.

```
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout
```

Multiple `local.xml` files in the fallback hierarchy are not taken into account. The first of these that can be found, is used:

```
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout/local.xml
app/design/frontend/[package]/default/layout/local.xml
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml
```

*(assuming default hierarchy and no custom defined hierarchy)*

**How to make changes**

You should only have modifications in local.xml, not repeat definitions that are already in the original XML files. That also means, avoid copying XML files from the default theme to make changes directly in the files. Keep your theme's `layout` directory clean!

Typical elements of `local.xml` are `<remove>` to remove existing blocks entirely, `<action method="unsetChild">` and `<action method="append">` to move a block from one parent to another, or calling any other methods on existing blocks to modify their behaviour.

**Magento 1.9**

Starting with Magento 1.9, best practise is actually to not use `layout/local.xml` for these changes, but `etc/theme.xml`

> In short, you can add a layout update in app/design/frontend/yourpackage/etc/theme.xml. The advantage is that you have control over the load order of your layout updates. Before Magento 1.9 local.xml was always loaded last, and it was impossible to have layout directives be executed after it.
>
> I’m not using local.xml any more for project-specific theme modifications. I think local.xml is just used for backward compatibility reasons (in 1.9 and above) as there is no point in using it any more. Local.xml is also eliminated in Magento 2 (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1037).

<sup>**Source: https://erfanimani.com/dont-use-local-xml/**</sup>