# Removing Header and Footer from Magento popup

Tags: layout, theme, local.xml, popup

With the reference from my yesterday question [CODE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72760/what-is-the-correct-way-approach-to-modify-a-magento-template), now I am able to show the send mail to friend in a popup with the below code in `test.phtml`( set it via `local.xml`)

**test.phtml**

```
<?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
    <li><a href='#' onclick="return showCompare('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>');" class="link-email-friend" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**JS code( test.phtml)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showCompare(url){
    win = new Window({ title: "Compare Products", url:url, zIndex:3000, destroyOnClose: true, recenterAuto:false, resizable: false, width:450, height:473, minimizable: false, maximizable: false, draggable: false});
    win.showCenter(true);
    }
</script>
```

Now the pop up is shown , but with whole page `layout ie Header & Footer` showing up, so I want here is to REMOVE the Header & Footer,

So After a careful inspection, I found out the particular block is residing in

> frontend/base/default/layout/sendfriend.xml

So What I did here is created a `local.xml` file to override( Header & Footer), with the below code

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <sendfriend_product_send translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product Email to a Friend</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <remove name="header"/>
            <remove name="footer"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="sendfriend/send" name="sendfriend.send" template="sendfriend/send.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </sendfriend_product_send>
</layout>
```

But unfortunately its not working , but when I place the same piece of code in `sendfriend.xml`, it works (removing Header & Footer).

I am a bit lost, as how I am gonna put things up her, I mean how to do this in a standard way ?

Comment: where did you put the local.xml file? By the way, you can also use `page/popup.phtml` as root template which shows just the content without header and footer

Comment: @fschmengler in the same directory ie frontend/base/default/layout/

Comment: That's the problem. You have to put it into the directory of the actual theme you use. local.xml files of parent themes are not taken into account.

Comment: ohh @fschmengler but sendfriend.xml is in frontend/base/default/layout/ directory

Comment: yes and that's fine as it is a theme independent layout file from a module. local changes belong to the theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `local.xml` file must be in the directory of the actual theme you are using, i.e.

```
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout
```

Multiple `local.xml` files in the fallback hierarchy are not taken into account. The first of these that can be found, is used:

```
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout/local.xml
app/design/frontend/[package]/default/layout/local.xml
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml
```

*(assuming default hierarchy and no custom defined hierarchy)*

Comment: It worked, but am I doing the right thing? I mean actual file has <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action> but in my default layout(local.xml) i have just used <sendfriend_product_send translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product Email to a Friend</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <remove name="header"/>
            <remove name="footer"/>
        </reference>
    </sendfriend_product_send>

Comment: Sounds right, you should only have modifications in local.xml, not repeat definitions that are already in the module's xml

Comment: I assume it will remove 'varien/product.js' which is present in main sendfriend.xml ..

Comment: check my answer that I posted please , give me a feedback

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code. ***No need to add reference for remove block***

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <sendfriend_product_send translate="label">
        ......
        <remove name="header"/>
        <remove name="footer"/>
        ......
    </sendfriend_product_send>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

A big thanks to @fshmengler for the quick solution ( it worked like an charm), later after a thoughtful thinking I just modified my `local.xml`

**from**

```
<sendfriend_product_send translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product Email to a Friend</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="header"/>
        <remove name="footer"/>
    </reference>
</sendfriend_product_send>
```

**to**

```
<sendfriend_product_send translate="label">
     <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popup.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</sendfriend_product_send>
```

Hope this is a good solution compare to removing Head & Footer ?

Comment: This should be an addition to your question (too long for a comment), not an answer on its own. But yes, if you do not require the sidebar column, this is the best solution.

Comment: well I am Glad ! Thanks, let this solution be here it might be helpful for others.. :)