# Setting the list grid as default when products are displayed using the search bar

Tags: search, catalogsearch, product-view

How to set the list grid to be the default preview when product/products are displayed using the search bar?

Comment: Are you saying that you want a different default mode (grid/list) on search result pages than in the catalog pages?

Comment: yes for example, when a customer is browsing through my shop and he observes products to see the products as grid, but when a customer is searching for a product/products i want the product to appear as list.

Comment: [Answered](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/74683/798) - hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please give me an extension for magento 2.1.9 for this title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<catalog_category_layered>
 <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
  <action method="setData">
   <key>_current_grid_mode</key>
   <value>grid</value>
  </action>
 </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: where do i have to add that?

Comment: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/72903/243

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Making catalogsearch use it's own template

Duplicate `list.phtml` like for example, `listsearch.phtml`.

Then you can either completely remove the list mode section if you don't want customers to be able to switch between modes or modify it to set the default...

Within `listsearch.phtml`, at the top of the page (just above `<div class="category-products">`), specify the default mode with:-

```
$this->getChild('toolbar')->setCurrentMode('grid');
```

Then make the catalog search use this new template file:-

```
<block type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result" template="catalogsearch/result.phtml">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/listsearch.phtml">
        <!-- etc etc -->
    </block>
</block>
```

### 2. Declaring the default mode via XML

In your `local.xml`, specify the config values for the `product_list_toolbar` like:-

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setData">
            <key>_current_grid_mode</key>
            <value>grid</value>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Either of these methods should work depending on the extend of how much you wish to customise the product listings in the catalog search results differently from the main catalog.