# How do I add a new template in magento?

Tags: layout, template

What I am trying to do is to create a new template in my theme. I created a file in **frontend/mytheme/default/template/page/2columns-left-cms.phtml**. This is the content of it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?> 
</head>
<body <?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
    <div class="breadcrumbs-list">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="container product-details-container">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
        <div class="layout layout-1-col home-main">
            <div role="main" class="role-main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I want to select from **cms/design** from **layout**, my new template, it doesn't show up. So what xml do i have to change ? what should i do ? Can someone explain the process?

Thank in Advance...

Comment: This answer might help you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72760/what-is-the-correct-way-approach-to-modify-a-magento-template/72903#72903

Comment: I am using magento 1.9. I read it what you suggested me, but I am still confused. Can you give me more documentation, or post an example ? thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

As it looks like you have FTP access. A quick extension would be..

create file under **app/etc/modules/My_Othertemplates.xml** with code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
  <My_Othertemplates>
  <codePool>community</codePool>
  <active>true</active>
  </My_Othertemplates>
 </modules>
</config>
```

..then create the Extension etc config file

```
app/code/community/My/Othertemplates/etc/config.xml
```

..with the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <global>
   <page>
    <layouts>
     <!-- My New Template -->
     <page_2colleftcms>
     <label>2 Column Left CMS (2colleftcms)</label>
     <template>page/2columns-left-cms.phtml</template>
     <layout_handle>page_2colleftcms</layout_handle>
     </page_2colleftcms>
    </layouts>
   </page>
  </global>
 </config>
```

this new template should appear in the select template dropdown across the admin panel.

You can add more as well inside the app/code/community/My/Othertemplates/etc/config.xml. Just change "2colleftcms" to a unique name and **make sure the template file exists** in your *theme folder* or *base folder*

```
<!-- Another New Template -->
<page_2colleftcms>
<label>2 Column Left CMS (2colleftcms)</label>
<template>page/2columns-left-cms.phtml</template>
<layout_handle>page_2colleftcms</layout_handle>
</page_2colleftcms>
```

I'm using this with success

Comment: I created this module. I put exactly what you described, I cleared the cached, the module is enabled, but nothing appears in the cms page in the dropdown from the admin panel

Comment: Well i just did the steps above (on Magento 1.9.0.1) and its showing up on my cms page layout dropdown menu..

Comment: but where should i put the 2columns-left-cms.phtml ? i put it in mytheme/default/template/page

Comment: <template>page/2columns-left-cms.phtml</template> this points to the specified path given, so yes, just place the template file in the path specified.

Comment: https://github.com/SeakEcommerce/AdditionalLayouts/blob/master/README.md - via GitHub repo

Answer (score -1):

```
<custommodule_cms_index>
        <!— Custom page layout handles —>
        <reference name=“root”>
            <action method=“setTemplate”><template>page/2columns-left-cms.phtml</template></action>
             <!— Mark root page block that template is applied —>
             <action method=“setIsHandle”><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </custommodule_cms_index>
```

or

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left-cms.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

More view: [Custom layout magento](http://blog.mage-express.com/magento-how-to-change-page-layout)