# How to customize a landing page layout so that a client can manage it?

Tags: layout-update, page-layouts, landing-pages

How can I customize several landing pages so the client can easily add/remove new categories without having to figure out the layout update bit.

Basically I have 2 types of landing pages, the default landing and a page for products that belong to an exploded view. In the exploded view product category I've added this to the layout update:

```
<reference name="content">
        <reference name="category.products">
            <action method="setTemplate"><file>catalog/category/exploded-view-landing.phtml</file></action>
        </reference>
</reference>

<reference name="root">
        <remove name="home.landing.catalog.product.new" />
</reference>
```

Which is fine, it works and allows me to setup a custom layout without issues.

HOWEVER

The client will need to add these "exploded view" pages on their own.  Finding, copying & pasting some XML from another resource isn't going to make them happy, I know it's pretty simple - but these are clients not developers.

Is there a way to achieve the same goal by using the local.xml and just having to train the client to "pick the right" layout/template from Page Layout drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can whip up a quick extension ([How do I add a new template in magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78743/how-do-i-add-a-new-template-in-magento/78790?noredirect=1#comment103092_78790)) to add new templates to the page layout drop down options for your client to easily select from.

Comment: https://github.com/SeakEcommerce/AdditionalLayouts/blob/master/README.md - via GitHub repo

Comment: Well, I got it to show up in the drop down, but I'm getting an error: Call to a member function getProductCount() on a non-object  .. I think it needs a little more info?

Comment: where is that error occurring? In the admin or frontend? If it in the frontend I would say you have an error in your phtml template file. This code is pretty basic so if and admin issue please post your config.xml

Comment: It's in the front end - I think the issue is really in the language of my question - what I am really trying to do is change the block - I'm probably getting the error because I am now trying to display a block as a template and key objects are not getting loaded. I think I can create a proper template for this & then specify which blocks to display in my local.xml for that template.  Gonna take some work though.