# How can i add some custom text to Cart Page?

Tags: cart, custom

Right when we click the cart icon we are taken to cart page where all product or products added to cart are shown.
On this page I want to add some custom text and icons below the cart summary by removing Estimated Shipping Tax and placing my text instead of Estimated Shipping Tax.
Please just tell where I can add these changes ?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/72903/243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento CE 1.9.2.1 the Estimated Shipping Tax is loaded in the following template file.

```
[your magento install dir]/app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

> If your theme does not contain this file then you can copy it from the
>   `/base/default/` theme and add it to your own theme.

Open this file and look for the following line of code

```
<?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
```

replace this line with the following lines of code

```
<!-- <?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?> -->
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

The **first line** comments the Estimated Shipping Tax preventing it from rendering. So it will no longer be displayed. The **second line** will insert a CMS Static block to the cart page with identifier `block_identifier`, but only if this static block is active.

In your Magento Admin Panel go to `CMS > Static Block` and click on the `Add New Block` button.

1. Fill in your new block title
2. Fill in your new block identifier (this is important and should match the identifier that you have used in the cart.phtml file)
3. Choose the proper store view(s)
4. Enable the block
5. Add the code for the custom text and icons that you want to display
6. Save the block

Now refresh all cache and go to your cart page. The Estimated Shipping Tax block should be replaced by your new text and icons.

Comment: That's great.You Rock. :)

Answer (score 0):

Magento has something called template path hints. Template path hints are little tags which would lie on top of your shop frontend. These little tags enable you to view where exactly the code of a specific element is stored within your file structure.

To activate template path hints:

1. Log into the magento back-end admin
2. Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
3. Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
4. Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or
   store view.
5. Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a
   new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path
   hints.

[Source](http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/12659-How-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-in-magento)

Comment: I find it bit sarcastic :) but let me check

Answer (score 0):

**To remove Estimated Shipping** 
In File

```
app/design/frontend/[YOUR THEME]/[YOUR PACKAGE]/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

Comment out below code

```
<?php //if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping');
        endif;
        ?>
```

or
In file

```
app/design/frontend/[YOUR THEME]/[YOUR PACKAGE]/layout/local.xml
```

add below code

```
<checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
```

**To Add custom cms static block at the same location as of shipping block** 
Create a CMS Static block and add below code in file `app/design/frontend/[YOUR THEME]/[YOUR PACKAGE]/template/checkout/cart.phtml` just before closing `div class="cart-forms"`

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_static_block_id')->toHtml(); ?>
```