# Magento Template Override

Tags: frontend

I would like to know how to change the template of

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

To a my custom template.

What is currently happening is it is showing two instance of catalog_product_view on the browser

I am using a custom module.

My Config:

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <towersystems_retailer>
            <file>retailer.xml</file>
        </towersystems_retailer>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

My Layout:

```
<layout>
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="custom/catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="custom/catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <!--
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
            -->
            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                <label>Alert Urls</label>
            </block>

            <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
                <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
                <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
            </block>

            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
            </block>
            <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
            <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

[image]

Comment: you want to change view.phtml right

Comment: yes. what happened was it is now showing twice.

Comment: you are using any custom module

Comment: Show me that screen shot of front end

Comment: I have updated the question and added a screenshot

Comment: screen shot is not display if you want to add new phtml just follow @Arunendra answer

Comment: after I've done that its now showing 3 instances of <catalog_product_view>

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72760/what-is-the-correct-way-approach-to-modify-a-magento-template/72903#72903

Comment: just enable template hints then you share the screen

Answer (score 2):

In your layout xml file you redefined a new product view block. What you need to do is reference the one that is already defined, and update it's template.

Your layout should look like this

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>custom/catalog/product/view.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Next, if you also want to override the block class, that should be done in the module's config.xml file:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view>Namespace_Custom_Block_Product_View</product_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And the Namespace_Custom_Block_Product_View* class must extend product view block:

```
class Namespace_Custom_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
```

Comment: would this still give me access to the block class?

Comment: To change / add block methods you need to override the block class. I edited the answer to include this information

Comment: There should be no need to rewrite the block. The first part of the answer is everything you need to change the template, it will still work with the same product block and you still can add additional changes (with `<action>`) or new child blocks (with `<block>`) to the `<reference>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding block in content so it will display twice. It should be like this

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="custom/catalog/product/view.phtml" />
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: @tom_cruz update this layout or you can go with Alex Dinca's answer

Comment: I did do that so what happened is that I just remove <reference name="content"> on the layout xml and it didnt show multiple instance. Would anybody now why is that?

Answer (score -1):

put this code in your layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>  
    <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="yourtemplatefile.phtml">
    </reference >
    </catalog_product_view> 
</layout>
```

Comment: its now showing 3 instance of catalog_product_view

Comment: Please put this code in your local.xml

Comment: Updated answer just paste it in local.xml and put file on you layout folder