# URL redirection in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, related-products

I'm new to Magento development. I was trying to display related products in the product view.

While method `->getName()` works fine, `->getProductUrl()` renders the path of the actual product. I tried create an external link for www.google.com, i had the same issue.

Thank you for your help.

Here is my code :

```
$categoryId = array_shift($_product->getCategoryIds());
$related_prods = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addUrlRewrite($categoryId)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',
                        array('in'=>$_product->getRelatedProductIds()));

<?php foreach($related_prods as $related) { ?>
<a href="<?php $related->getProductUrl()."<br />";?>">
<?php echo $related->getName();?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: please post your code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, code for loading the related products already exists in the core. There is a block that shows related products and in the default themes you don't even need to do anything to show it. If it is missing in your theme, you can add this to your theme's layout XML:

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml" />
</reference>
```

And in the product template, where you want to show the related products:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products'); ?>
```

Now you can adjust `catalog/product/list/related.phtml` to change the HTML, or create a new template and change the path in the XML above.

Minimal working template example with name and URL:

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>">
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you don't understand where to add which code, read: [What is the correct way/approach to modify a Magento template?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72760/what-is-the-correct-way-approach-to-modify-a-magento-template/72903#72903)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about question,may be  want to get product url with category path.

**First,you should reindex  for generate proper url for getProductUrl()**

*`addUrlRewrite()`* function add *`category path`* to  ***product url*** whenever the setting ***`Use Categories Path for Product URLs`*** [ setting location **admin>system>Configuration>Catalog>Catalog/Search Engine Optimization**]  is **yes**  for current store  other wise magento cannot append category path to url.

You can see that condition at  class *Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection*.

```
   public function addUrlRewrite($categoryId = '')
    {
        $this->_addUrlRewrite = true;
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::XML_PATH_PRODUCT_URL_USE_CATEGORY, $this->getStoreId())) {
            $this->_urlRewriteCategory = $categoryId;
        } else {
            $this->_urlRewriteCategory = 0;
        }

        if ($this->isLoaded()) {
            $this->_addUrlRewrite();
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Also ***addUrlRewrite()*** only except one category id of a particular collection and does not support  multiple  categories ids of certain  product collection.

Else, `array_shift($_product->getCategoryIds());` is not proper way  to  get `category  ids`.,because of `getCategoryIds()`  give a array like

Assume that  product have two category ids

Then out put like `['0'=>'Cat_ID_first','1'=>'Cat_ID_Second']`.

**So, array_shift is not proper way get category Id.**
If you have single category id then  use

```
if(count($_product->getCategoryIds())>0):
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryId = $categoryIds[0] ;

... do what ever
endif;
```

Comment: Thank for you answer. The answer that was given above was correct and i forgot to accept it.