# How to convert Delivery Day to Delivery Date?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, extensions, shipping

We can set `Deliver Day` such as `Delivery: 2 to 4 Days` through creating attribute.

But I want to show the `DATE` instead of DAYS.

Example: `Delivery: Between 18 March & 20 March` (if today is 16 March)

[Click here to Check the live Example](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/AMARI-MODERN-DESIGNER-DOUBLE-KING-SIZE-LEATHER-BED-MEMORY-FOAM-MATTRESS-/121776048568?var=&clk_rvr_id=1182663280243&rmvSB=true)

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are rendered in the template `catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`. You can add a condition there that handles your "delivery_day" attribute differently:

```
if ($_data['code'] === "delivery_day") {
    // use PHP here to map the atttribute value $_data['value'] to a date expression
}
```

#### Useful functions:

- [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime): `strotime("+2 days")` gives the timestamp for two days from now
- [date()](http://php.net/date): formats a date

Read here how to change templates: [What is the correct way/approach to modify a Magento template?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72760/what-is-the-correct-way-approach-to-modify-a-magento-template/72903#72903)